# Python: Tesseract cannot find temp folder

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to use Tesseract on my Mac to OCR scan PDF files.
I get an FileNotFoundError like this one:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/nd/wvx6zxqs6c990_7cwkdg9gp40000gp/T/tess_ctoi9yiv.pdf'`. The folder is always the same, the file name changes.

This is my code:

```
import io
import os
from pathlib import Path

import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileMerger

os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/tessdata/"


class Paths:
    project_path = Path(__file__).parent
    data_dir = project_path / "data"
    pdf_dir = data_dir / "pdfs"
    json_dir = data_dir / "json"
    data_csv = data_dir / "data.csv"
    pdf_to_scan = data_dir / "pdf_to_scan"
    pdf_file = pdf_to_scan / "file_002.pdf"
    out_dir = pdf_dir
    out_file = out_dir / "file_002_.pdf"

merger = PdfFileMerger()

tessdata_dir_config = f'--tessdata-dir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/tessdata/'


image_file_list = []

pdf_pages = convert_from_bytes(open(Paths.pdf_file, "rb").read())
for page_enumeration, page in enumerate(pdf_pages, start=1):
    filename = f"{Paths.pdf_to_scan}/page_{page_enumeration:03}.jpg"
    page.save(filename, "JPEG")
    image_file_list.append(filename)

for i in range(len(image_file_list)):
    with open(Paths.out_file, "ab") as file:
        print(f"{image_file_list[i]=}")
        result =  pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(image_file_list[i], lang="deu", config=tessdata_dir_config)
        pdf_file_in_memory = io.BytesIO(result)
        merger.append(pdf_file_in_memory)
merger.write(Paths.out_file)
merger.close()
```

The error ist raised in the line `result =  pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(image_file_list[i], lang="deu", config=tessdata_dir_config)`.

The full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path_to_my_project/test.py", line 42, in <module>
    result =  pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(image_file_list[i], lang="deu", config=tessdata_dir_config)
  File "/path_to_my_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 446, in image_to_pdf_or_hocr
    return run_and_get_output(*args)
  File "/path_to_my_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 290, in run_and_get_output
    with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/nd/wvx6zxqs6c990_7cwkdg9gp40000gp/T/tess_jgf5pkr_.pdf'
```

My OS is Sonoma 14.0, I installed Tesseract 5.3.3 with brew. The installed version of pytesseract is 0.3.10.

I tried to find a possibility to set the temp folder, but I couldn’t find one. I searched for "pytesseract temp folder" and "tesseract temp folder", but found nothing that helped me.